# Login de Laravel no funciona

Tags: c#, laravel

Tengo una aplicacion desarrollada en C#, y necesito que mis usuarios ahoran puedan usar tanto la aplicacion de escritorio como la version web, para dar un poco mas de contexto a lo que esta sucediendo, mi tabla Usuarios tiene los sientes campos:

- idUsuario
- Usuario
- [Nombre del Empleado]
- Contraseña
- password (se añadio para probar la funcion de hash de c# y asegurarnos que sea compatible con laravel)
- Sucursal
- Correo

etc

Se ingreso la contraseña incorrecta me muestra el siguiente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si ingreso bien la contraseña me retorna de  nuevo al login.

Esto es lo que tengo hecho en laravel hasta el momento:

esta es mi clase users de laravel:

```
  protected $table = "Usuarios";
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'Usuario', 'Correo', 'password', 'Nombre Completo del Empleado', 'Contraseña'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];
```

Aqui esta mi LoginController

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function username()
    {
        return 'Usuario';
    }


}
```

y este es mi login de blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="Usuario" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Usuario') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="Usuario" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('Usuario') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="Usuario" value="{{ old('Usuario') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('Usuario'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('Usuario') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Iniciar Sesion') }}
                                </button>                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Que tiene que ver la etiqueta C#

Comment: Porque tal ves alguien aparte de mi ya ha hecho algo similar

Comment: ¿Cómo están definidas las rutas en laravel?

Comment: Es un proyecto nuevo, estoy comenzando con el login para asegurarme que mi funcion de bcrypt de C# funciona bien, tiene las rutas y middleware por defecto, tambien estoy usando wampp server, y ya tengo virtualizado la pagina

Comment: añade en tu modelo de usuario el primaryKey, aun que no estoy seguro que funcione. Otra cosa que podrías hacer es modificar el modelo de user en el auth.php que esta en config, Creando un modelo desde cero y pasando los parámetros a Auth::loginUsingId($id); o cualquiera de los métodos del facde auth

Comment: igual podrías inspeccionar la respuesta en el netword del navegador para que veamos más a detalle el error que esta mandando.

Comment: ese es el detalle no muestra ningun mensaje de error, simplemente no pasa a la vista home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

despues de mucho, encontre la solucion, en realidad tenia que realizar varias cosas, primero en mi clase users, tengo que añadir la llave primaria, luego tengo que hacer el login de manera manual:

```
    public function login()
{
    $credentials= $this->validate(request(),[
        $this->username()=> 'required|string',
        'password'=>'required|string'
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials))
    {    
        Auth::loginUsingId(Auth::user()->userTablePrimaryKey);
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
    return back()->withErrors([$this->username()=>trans('auth.failed')])
                 ->withInput(request([$this->username()]));
}
```

ya con esto la autenticacion queda almacenada sin necesidad de agregar otros middleware

Answer (score 0):

El problema por lo que veo radica en el cambio de los nombres de las columnas de las tablas, por defecto se usan en ingles, y lo que tendrías que hacer es cambiar el controlador de Laravel que se ubica en "vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php", pero eso traera consigo varios problemas.

Comment: David gracias por el aporte pero tu respuesta parece mas un comentario. Te sugiero que realices el [tour] así conoces mas sobre el sitio y obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges), También podrías revisar [Como Responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Después de lo que habías realizado en tu pregunta, solo era necesario agregar a tu modelo de usuarios la nueva llave primaria de forma literal, asi:

```
protected $primaryKey = "nombreLlavePrimaria";
```

Y listo, tu login ya debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se soluciona en el modelo User.php agregando

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

Y listo, funciona el Login, a mi me funcionó